# jqgrid hidden columns contribute to row height calculation

Tags: javascript, css, jqgrid

I have create a jqgrid and a few of the columns are hidden. The css attribute

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
white-space: normal !important;
}
```

is used to take care for overflowing texts. Row height is set to 'auto'. The columns are hidden using hidden:"true" attribute.

Now, one of the hidden column contains large text which making the row height larger. How can I make sure that the row height is computed only based on the displayed column contents?

Looking forward for your help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Now, if I reduce the text length in the hidden column, it reduces the height of the row as shown below.

[image]

How can I achieve the height as in second screenshot so that the hidden column contents does not affect row height?

Comment: Can you display: none on all internal elements of hidden columns?
ex:
.hidden_column td > * {
  display: none
}

Comment: @K.F I checked the columns and all the hidden columns have display: none applied.

Comment: Would it be possible to reproduce this in a codepen? or with some images to better demonstrate what the issue is?

Comment: @K.F attached some screenshots to make things clear.

Comment: I noticed one more thing. The header columns have the style="display:none;" like <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:150px;display:none;"></td>. However, the hidden columns of the data rows do not have style="display:none;" as you can see in the screenshot. I think that is causing the issue. If I can ensure the data rows for hidden columns have display:none, it will work. I tested it. But how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the hidden property in colModel as:

```
hidden:"true"
```

When I changed it to:

```
hidden:true
```

It works! Because, the data rows for hidden columns now have the style="display:none;".

Thanks!